# capturing and replacing each word in a list surrounded brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have a text such as

```
"tnheitanhiaiin [ hello, there, will, you, help ] thitnahioetnaeitn
tnhetnh [ me, figure, this, out ] ihnteahntanitnh
nhoietnaiotniaehntehtnea [ please, because, i, dont, know ] thnthen
"
```

How do I capture each word inside the brackets so I can surround them with single quotes?

I tried `\[\s?(?:(\w*),?\s?)+\]` but it doesnt seem to be able to capture anything although it matches the bracketed parts.

The words inside the brackets can be anything.

I'm hoping to use gsub on each line.

Comment: sorry, updated with more info.

Comment: I need to capture each word inside the brackets only to add single quotes around each. Also I'm hoping to do a one pass substitution on each line using gsub

Comment: This affects the text outside of the brackets too. Another thing, if possible, i'd like a regex solution without using map, join, etc. Basically pure string substitution only using gsub and regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = /
    (?<=[ ])  # match a space in a positive lookbehind
    \p{L}+    # match one or more letters
    (?=       # begin a positive lookahead
      [^\[]+? # match one or more characters other than a left bracket, lazily
      \]      # match a right bracket
    )         # end the positive lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Letting `str` be the string defined in the question, we can surround the words between brackets with single quotes as follows.

```
str.gsub(r) { |s| "'#{s}'" }
  #=> "tnheitanhiaiin [ 'hello', 'there', 'will', 'you', 'help' ]
  #    thitnahioetnaeitn\ntnhetnh [ 'me', 'figure', 'this', 'out' ]
  #    ihnteahntanitnh\nnhoietnaiotniaehntehtnea [ 'please', 'because',
  #    'i', 'dont', 'know' ] thnthen\n"
```

If, instead, we wish to extract those words, we would us [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

```
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["hello", "there", "will", "you", "help", "me", "figure", "this",
  #    "out", "please", "because", "i", "dont", "know"]
```

The question mark at the end of `[^\[]+?` (to match lazily, rather than greedily) is present to improve efficiency, but is not required.

I've used free-spacing definition mode to make the regex self-documenting. Conventionally it would be written as follows.

```
     /(?<= )\p{L}+(?=[^\[]+?\])/
```

This assumes that (as in the example) the brackets are matching and not nested and that the words with brackets are preceded by a space and followed by a comma or a space. The regex could be adjusted if the assumption pertaining to the characters surrounding words between brackets is incorrect.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much and for the detailed explanation of the regex!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
original = "tnheitanhiaiin [ hello, there, will, you, help ] thitnahioetnaeitn\ntnhetnh [ me, figure, this, out ] ihnteahntanitnh\nnhoietnaiotniaehntehtnea [ please, because, i, dont, know ] thnthen\n"
clone = original
original.scan(/\[(.*)\]/).flatten.map { |elem| [elem, elem.gsub(/\w+/) { |match| %Q('#{match}') }] }.each { |(pattern, replacement)| clone.gsub!(pattern, replacement) }
puts clone # =>
# tnheitanhiaiin [ 'hello', 'there', 'will', 'you', 'help' ] thitnahioetnaeitn
# tnhetnh [ 'me', 'figure', 'this', 'out' ] ihnteahntanitnh
# nhoietnaiotniaehntehtnea [ 'please', 'because', 'i', 'dont', 'know' ] thnthen
```

Comment: thanks. this works but I'm going to wait to see if there's a pure regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a double-gsub along the lines of:

```
s = "tnheitanhiaiin [ hello, there, will, you, help ] thitnahioetnaeitn\ntnhetnh [ me, figure, this, out ] ihnteahntanitnh\nnhoietnaiotniaehntehtnea [ please, because, i, dont, know ] thnthen\n"

s.gsub(/\[.*?\]/) { |m| m.gsub(/\w+/, '\'\0\'') }
 #=> "tnheitanhiaiin [ 'hello', 'there', 'will', 'you', 'help' ] thitnahioetnaeitn\ntnhetnh [ 'me', 'figure', 'this', 'out' ] ihnteahntanitnh\nnhoietnaiotniaehntehtnea [ 'please', 'because', 'i', 'dont', 'know' ] thnthen\n"
```